# SQL Nomenclature: "Query" or "Command" for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?

Tags: sql, command, terminology

Which is more proper to call `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements? Command or query? I would think "command," since "query" implies that you are asking a question and expecting to get your question answered (and more information than just "yes, this operation was performed successfully, and, optionally, here's your insert ID").

Just a question from a mid-level web application developer who was also an communications major and is one who enjoys specificity.

Comment: Well, almost all the SQL books I have red, says `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` command

Comment: I needed to create Abstract classes for my team in order to implement the Unit of Work, Command pattern with Entity Framework. I wanted the abstract classes to have a template Execute method that took care of setup and saveChanges so the naming was important. Things I came up with: AbstractMutateCommand, AbstractUpdateCommand, AbstractWriteCommand. Picked the last one.

Comment: I'm looking for the same - a term for `select/insert/update/delete`, but **not** for procedure call. I think I'll call it "statement".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The generic term for a `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` is an "update" (even though it is potentially confusing -- and not ideal -- that `UPDATE` is merely a subset of "update"). An alternative term is "relational assignment".

The generic term for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE` (and anything else terminated by a semicolon) is known as a "statement".

Strictly speaking, a "query" is a `SELECT` statement that returns a resultset (which would for example preclude `SELECT..INTO..FROM` statements). However, using the term "query" to refer to an update, while informal, is unfortunately very common. For example, although "update query" is an oxymoron, when I do a Google search for this site using that exact term (`site:stackoverflow.com "update query"`) I get 17,300 hits!

---

UPDATE (pun indended :)

> @David Marx: I disagree with your claim that it's appropriate to refer
>   to INSERT/DELETE/MERGE as an 'update.' That would be extremely
>   confusing. Only UPDATE is an update.

I agreed in my original answer that the situation is potentially confusing. We are fortunate on Stackoverflow to be able to format answers and comments so that a keyword `UPDATE` can be differentiated from a logical update; writing keywords in upper case (as required by Full Standard SQL-92 :) also helps.

However, from reading the general database and computing science literature, I can tell you that 'update' is indeed the correct collective term. I below provide a citation for this:

"An Introduction to Relational Database Theory" (2010), Hugh Darwen [available as a free pdf download -- Google it):

> The different update operators expected in a relational DBMS are
>   usually called `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`, and those are the
>   names used in Tutorial D (also in SQL) [p.28]
>
> It is regrettable that the keyword `UPDATE` has become so widely
>   accepted as the name of just one particular operator for updating
>   databases. Please don't shoot the messenger! [p.168]
>
> although [relational] assignment is theoretically sufficient for
>   updating purposes, it is usually more convenient to use a shorthand
>   expressing the difference between the current value of the target
>   relvar and the new value. Sometimes... that difference is just the
>   addition of one or more tuples to the existing set; sometimes it is
>   just changes to some of the attribute values of some of the existing
>   tuples; and sometimes it is just the removal of some of the existing
>   tuples. Shorthands for those three particular cases have been referred
>   to as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` respectively, since time
>   immemorial -- in other words, even before the advent of relational
>   databases, though of course before that advent the targets of the
>   updates were files, not relvars or SQL tables [p.165]

Comment: I disagree with your claim that it's appropriate to refer to INSERT/DELETE/MERGE as an 'update.' That would be extremely confusing. Only UPDATE is an update.

Comment: @David Marx: see the update to my answer. Also, consider if my `MERGE` was of the variety `MERGE..IF MATCHED THEN UPDATE..` could that be considered an `UPDATE` as well as an update? ;)

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, call it a "statement."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes anything other than select is considered to be DML - Data Manipulation Language.  However this is not a hard and fast distinction.  That is just as often select is included within DML.